# Carthage: The dependency graph contained a cycle while using Forked LoopKit

Tags: ios, swift, shell, carthage, build-script

**Describe the bug**
I'm trying to develop a modified version of LoopKit dependecy and want to include it on Loop project with new features.
When I tried to add a fresh fork of LoopKit in Cartfile (setting the carfile.resolved to pick the same commit from forked repo)and tried to build it, It gave the follow error:

"The dependency graph contained a cycle"

I think the issue is due to LoopKit being used by dependencies of Loop project. Like G4SharedSpy, riley_link, BLEKit and dexcom is also using LoopKit as dependency.

But the error won't appear if I use LoopKit/LoopKit in Loop project instead of using forked repo, i.e ZUCheema/LoopKit.

I tried to clone all the dependencies and used forked repo of LoopKit for all but it created more issues like git index.lock conflict and would download multiple versions of LoopKit while carthage update.

**Attach an Issue Report**
Here's what XCode outputs:
`
The dependency graph contained a cycle:

Amplitude-iOS:

CGMBLEKit: dexcom-share-client-swift, LoopKit

MKRingProgressView:

dexcom-share-client-swift: LoopKit

LoopKit: SwiftCharts

SwiftCharts:

G4ShareSpy: dexcom-share-client-swift, LoopKit

rileylink_ios: MKRingProgressView, LoopKit

`

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

Go to Cartfile
Replace github "LoopKit/LoopKit" "dev" to your own forked repo
Build XCode project
See error
**Expected behavior**
XCode project would not build with forked LoopKit repo.